# How to show database table data into labels text with loop in c# windows form

Tags: c#, database, winforms, loops, label

I'm facing a problem to show database data into labels. I have a database table name is EMP, EMP has 5 columns, I want all EMP data into labels using a loop. please see the image below for better understanding.

Image:
[image] 
I write blow code for that but this code the only one row of database table, how I get all rows in labels. Please help...

```
using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(Connection.Conn()))
            {
                string CommandText = "SELECT * FROM EMP";
                using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(CommandText, conn))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    SQLiteDataAdapter sda = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    sda.Fill(ds);

                    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        label1.Text = dr["EmpCode"].ToString();
                        label2.Text = dr["EmpName"].ToString();
                        label3.Text = dr["EmpCity"].ToString();
                        label4.Text = dr["EmpState"].ToString();
                    }
                 }
              }
```

Please help me to find the way of showing all data into labels using loop, any code or link will help.

Comment: You'd have to put four labels per row in the loop into your form. That's possible though maybe a bit more complicated than it needs to be. You may have a look at more suitable controls like the [`DataGrid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagrid?view=netframework-4.8) for example.

Comment: This is really not the way to generate this kind of layout. Use a DataGridView. You just need to set its DataSource to the DataTable: `dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]`. If you don't have a Column which provides the serial number, you can add one to the DataTable, setting it to auto-increment its content: `DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("Name") { AutoIncrement = true, AutoIncrementSeed = 0, AutoIncrementStep = 1, DataType = typeof(long) }; ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add(dc);`. In the DataGridView, you ca show it in any position: `dataGridView1.Columns["Name"].DisplayIndex = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this for every label

```
label1.Text += dr["EmpCode"].ToString() + "<br />";
```

Or better you should look at datagridview http://csharp.net-informations.com/datagridview/csharp-datagridview-tutorial.htm

I think too that it would be better